# Cannot login to phpPgAdmin after installing postgres 16.1 in XAMPP (Windows)

Tags: postgresql, windows, xampp, phppgadmin

I followed this [tutorial](https://gioele-bencivenga.github.io/random%20knowledge/Integrating-Postgres-Xampp_PhpPgAdmin/) on how to install postgres in XAMPP in Windows. Everything went well but when I navigated to http://localhost/phpPgAdmin/, it asks for username and password. I am just wondering what is the default login account for this?

During the installation, I set the password to **incorrect** but it does not work also. I tried re-installing the whole thing but still the same

I already tried the following but none works:

username: postgres
password: incorrect

username: postgres
password: root

username postgres
password: 1234

username: admin
password: root